# Disqus privacy icon misaligned

Tags: css, jekyll, disqus

I'm trying to integrate Disqus into my Jekyll blog however when I view the website on my iPhone6 the Privacy icon is misaligned like so:

[image]

Is there a way to modify or fix this?

Comment: It looks like it has not enough space, I can't do much without actually markup

Comment: Lets start with some code sharing.